# thymeleaf Springboot Page not refresh When I click next (preview) button in fragment

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I’m use my fragment to refresh data in table when I enter page and input filter keyword.

If I’m not add the js to build the enter next page, it is work correct in enter page show list.
(I have certify my controller and service is okey)

But when I add the ajax to fetch(post) data and refresh data in table, the next page number still not auto refresh.(/*[[${response.number}]]*/ not refresh, still 1)

is adding  something after ajax code in fragment or js?

where are the mistake ? thank you.

```
                       .....
                       .....
 
                       <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName">Name</label> <input
                                    type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName"
                                    placeholder=“u”serName>
                       </div>

                       ......
                       ......
            <div class="row mt-5">
               <div class="col">

                <div th:fragment="filteredList" id="filteredList">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover"
                        id="devicesTable">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="users,iter : ${response.content}">
                                <td class="text-info text-center"
                                    th:text=“${users.name}"></td>
                                <td class="text-left" th:text="${users.department}"></td>
                                <td class="text-center"
                                    th:text="${#dates.format(users.updateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')}"></td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                                         <nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="mt-4">
                        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                            
                            <li class="page-item"
                                th:classappend="${response.isFirst()} ? disabled: '' "><a
                                id="firstPageBtn" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">firstPage</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"
                                th:classappend="${response.isFirst()} ? disabled: '' "><a
                                id="prePageBtn" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Pre Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"
                                th:classappend="${response.isLast()} ? disabled: '' "><a
                                id="nextPageBtn" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Next Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item"
                                th:classappend="${response.isLast()} ? disabled: '' "><a
                                id="lastPageBtn" class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Last Page</a>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>


               .....
              .....


      <script th:inline="javascript">

     $('#inlineFormInputName').on('keyup', function() {
        var myvalue = $(this).val();
        fetchListData(myvalue, 0);

    });

    
    $(document).on('click','#firstPageBtn',function(){
        var inputKeyword =  $('#inlineFormInputName').val()
        var currentPageNumber = 0;
        fetchListData(inputKeyword, currentPageNumber)
    });
    
    $(document).on('click','#prePageBtn',function(){
        var inputKeyword =  $('#inlineFormInputName').val()
        var currentPageNumber = /*[[${response.number-1}]]*/0;
        fetchListData(inputKeyword, currentPageNumber)
    });
    $(document).on('click','#nextPageBtn',function(){
        var inputKeyword =  $('#inlineFormInputName').val()
        var currentPageNumber = /*[[${response.number}]]*/0;
        currentPageNumber = currentPageNumber +1;
        fetchListData(inputKeyword, currentPageNumber)
    });
    $('#lastPageBtn').click(function(e) {
        var currentPageNumber = /*[[${response.totalPages-1}]]*/0;
        fetchListData(inputKeyword, currentPageNumber)
        
    });

   function fetchListData(myvalue, page) {
        
             /*<![CDATA[*/
             var baseUrl = "/filterUsersListByKeyword";
             var fullUrl = new URL(baseUrl, document.location);
             fullUrl.searchParams.append("type", 1);
             fullUrl.searchParams.append("name", encodeURI(myvalue));
             fullUrl.searchParams.append("userId", "id0001");  //fake data
             fullUrl.searchParams.append("page", page);
             fullUrl.searchParams.append("size", 6);

             /*]]>*/
             $.ajax({
                 url : fullUrl,
                type : 'POST',
                success : function(response) {
                $('#filteredList').html(response);

                }
            })
         }
   </script>
```

Comment: Your AJAX call updates the HTML contents of the `#filteredList` tag, but it does not reload the full page, so the Thymeleaf variables in the JavaScript functions are never evaluated again.

Comment: I'm not reload full page, If I just reload table data(my fragment) and next(etc) page button, how can I do? thank you.

Comment: I had use ajax post filterUsersListByKeyword API, it's return ModelAndView and Pageable.@@